# how to use dictionary field in Django?

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I need to use dictionary field on a Django Model.

for example, on a data

```
name = Kim, user_id = 12902938291, dictionary = {'yo' : 'drop', 'the': 'beat'}
```

I know about model `serialization` but it doesn't satisfy my requirement.

How to use dictionary field in Django?

Answer (score 0):

Another clean and fast solution can be found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.JSONField

For convenience I copied the simple instructions.

**Usage**

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    json = JSONField()
```

Comment: Just to note: JSONField comes built-in with Django 3.1 (the next release around the corner), https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/3.1/

Comment: Thank you. Code has modified